# Injecting dependecy in services in component based strucuture

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I follow modular or component based strucutre. I found a sample repo.

https://github.com/sujeet-agrahari/node-express-clean-architecture

So, there is a main component.module.js files which is responsible for connecting all other pieces like controller, route, and services.

For controller, services are being injected using higher order functions. Now, controller are super easy to test, I can stub or mock services easily.

**auth.module.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const {
  makeExpressCallback,
  makeValidatorCallback,
} = require('../../middlewares');

// validator
const AuthValidator = require('./auth.validator');

// service
const { doRegister, doLogin, doCheckUserExist } = require('./auth.service');

const { BadRequestError } = require('../../utils/api-errors');

// controller
const controller = require('./auth.controller');

const register = controller.register({ BadRequestError, doCheckUserExist, doRegister });
const login = controller.login({ doCheckUserExist, doLogin });

const AuthController = { register, login };

// routes
const routes = require('./auth.routes')({
  router,
  AuthController,
  AuthValidator,
  makeValidatorCallback,
  makeExpressCallback,
});

module.exports = {
  AuthController,
  AuthService: {
    doCheckUserExist,
    doLogin,
    doRegister,
  },
  AuthRoutes: routes,
};
```

**auth.controller.js**

```
const login = (doCheckUserExist, doLogin) => async (httpRequest) => {
  const { username, password } = httpRequest.body;
  const userData = await doCheckUserExist({ username });
  const loginData = {
    username,
    role: userData.role_id,
    passedPassword: password,
    actualPassword: userData.password,
  };
  const loginResult = await doLogin(loginData);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      success: true,
      message: 'Successfully logged in!',
      data: loginResult,
    },
  };
};

const register = ({ BadRequestError, doCheckUserExist, doRegister }) => async (httpRequest) => {
  const { username, password } = httpRequest.body;
  try {
    await doCheckUserExist({ username });
  } catch (error) {
    // user doesn't exist
    const registerResult = await doRegister({ username, password });
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: {
        success: true,
        message: 'Registered successfully!',
        data: registerResult,
      },
    };
  }
  throw new BadRequestError('User already exist!');
};

module.exports = { register, login };
```

Things are fine with the controller, now the problem is with the services. I can't find any pattern to make them thin and clean.

**auth.services.js**

```
const {
  JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN,
  SIGN_OPTION,
} = require('config');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { User } = require('../../db');
const { generateJWT } = require('./jwt.service');
const { NotFoundError, BadRequestError } = require('../../utils/api-errors');

const doRegister = async ({ username, password }) => {
  const user = await User.create({
    username,
    password,
    role_id: 1, // assign role id here
  });
    // generate access token
  const payload = {
    username,
    role: user.role_id,
  };
  const token = await generateJWT({
    secretKey: JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    payload,
    signOption: {
      ...SIGN_OPTION,
      expiresIn: ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN,
    },
  });
  return {
    access_token: token,
    ...payload,
  };
};

const doLogin = async ({
  username, userRole, passedPassword, actualPassword,
}) => {
  const isValidPass = bcrypt.compareSync(passedPassword, actualPassword);
  if (!isValidPass) throw new BadRequestError('Username or Password is invalid!');
  // generate access token
  const payload = {
    username,
    role: userRole,
  };
  const token = await generateJWT({
    secretKey: JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    payload,
    signOption: {
      ...SIGN_OPTION,
      expiresIn: ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN,
    },
  });
  return {
    access_token: token,
    ...payload,
  };
};
const doCheckUserExist = async ({ username }) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      username,
    },
  });
  if (!user) throw new NotFoundError('User not found!');
  return user;
};

module.exports = { doRegister, doLogin, doCheckUserExist };
```

A lot is happening in the services, model imports, constants imports, and other utils.

Now services become really hard to test.

Is there any way or pattern I can separate some logic from services and make them lighter?

I can implement reository pattern for db methods, but I am not aware how I can implement using sequelize?

Should I use also higher order function to inject all the utils and constants in the service like I did for controller?